# How the ICE decides whether to use STUN or TURN in order to find the public IP address of a device?

Tags: android

I am trying to establish connection between devices in WebRTC. The devices are behinf NAT, hence the public IP address has to be determined. I learnt that STUN is used to find the public IP of the device. But if STUN fails, then TURN server is used. I also learnt that ICE is the mechanism which handles this. I would like to know how ICE works? How it determines whether to use STUN or TURN? How does it determine failure of STUN and immediately switches to TURN?

Answer (score 0):

"I also learn that ICE is the mechanism which handles this"

Yes you are right about that. But it is hard to explain your questions answer by giving answer here as a comment. I would suggest you, if you really interested on NAT Traversal then at first read following IETF RFC.

[ICE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245)

[STUN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389)

After reading these RFC, if you have any particular questions then you could ask here.